# Ubuntu block access from ip except one port

Tags: ip, iptables

How can I block access on all port except one eg `9999` to a server from specific IP eg `192.168.0.1` ?

`iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.1 -j DROP` will block all of ports.

Is there a possibility to block port range for specific IP?

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course there is!

`iptables` rules apply in order. So you may start by a very restrictive policy for your chain, and then allow traffic on specific ports.

You may first set default CHAIN policies like : (by default they are set as ACCEPT)

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

This way you're configuring every CHAIN to reject anything.
Then you can allow traffic by just one port, or just some network segment, as you like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

`INPUT` is the name of the CHAIN you're adding the rule, `-i` is for specifying which interface the rule applies to (`eth0` in the example) `-p` is used to specify the protocol (`tcp`) in this case, with `--dport` you specify on which port you are allowing traffic, `-m state` instructs the firewall to look at the connection state, this is for you to be able to use `--state NEW,ESTABLISHED` which are the two states on which the connection is permitted, finally `-j ACCEPT` tells the firewall that connections made that match the previously described rule will be accepted.

As your final question asks for ranges of IP and/or Ports the way to acomplish this is by using `--dport 80:10010` (rule applies to ports from 80 to 10010) and for the IP range you can use `-m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.100-192.168.1.200` so the rule will apply to any traffic comming from any ip in the range 192.168.1.100 - 192.168.1.200

Full working example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80:10010 -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.100-192.168.1.200 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```